# cURL Release Mode Invalid Parameter

Tags: c++, libcurl

I am working on a C++ program that uses cURL to "sign" into my Valorant account. The code works just fine in debug mode (Visual Studio 2019) but has an Invalid Parameter error when I switch to release mode. After doing some research I found that it was because of libcurl, but there were no fixes online. I am also using [json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) and a small code snippet for base64 decoding, but I believe those are irrelevant. My project properties are whatever the default properties are, I even tried making a new project and copying my code over but got the same result.
Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "json.hpp"
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "base64.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>

using json = nlohmann::json;


CURL* hnd = curl_easy_init();


size_t WriteCallback(char* contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* userp)
{
    ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}

void authCookies()
{

    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_URL, "https://auth.riotgames.com/api/v1/authorization");

    struct curl_slist* headers = NULL;
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");
    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);

    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"client_id\":\"play-valorant-web-prod\",\"nonce\":\"1\",\"redirect_uri\":\"https://playvalorant.com/opt_in\",\"response_type\":\"token id_token\"}");

    CURLcode ret = curl_easy_perform(hnd);
}


std::string getAuthToken(std::string username, std::string password)
{
    std::string token = "";
    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_URL, "https://auth.riotgames.com/api/v1/authorization");

    struct curl_slist* headers = NULL;
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");
    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
    std::string response;
    json toSend = {
        {"type", "auth"},
        {"username", username},
        {"password", password},
        {"remember", false},
        {"language", "en_US"}
    };

    std::string sendText = toSend.dump(4);
    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, sendText.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &response);
    CURLcode ret = curl_easy_perform(hnd);
    json resp = json::parse(response);

    //parse the uri and look for a token
    std::string uri = std::string(resp["response"]["parameters"]["uri"]);
    size_t loc = uri.find("#access_token=");

    for (int i = loc + 14; i < uri.length(); i++)
    {
        if (uri[i] != '&') { token += uri[i]; }
        else { break; }
    }
    return token;
}

void cookieReauth()
{
    std::string response;
    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_URL, "https://auth.riotgames.com/authorize?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fplayvalorant.com%2Fopt_in&client_id=play-valorant-web-prod&response_type=token%20id_token");
    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "");
    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &response);
    CURLcode ret = curl_easy_perform(hnd);
}

std::string getEntitlement(std::string token)
{
    std::string out = "";

    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_URL, "https://entitlements.auth.riotgames.com/api/token/v1");

    struct curl_slist* headers = NULL;
    std::string auth = "Authorization: Bearer " + token;
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, auth.c_str());
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");
    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "");

    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &out);
    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);

    CURLcode ret = curl_easy_perform(hnd);

    json resp = json::parse(out);
    return std::string(resp["entitlements_token"]);
}

struct valorantUser
{
    std::string displayName;
    std::string puuid;
    std::string name;
    std::string tag;
};

std::vector<valorantUser> getUsersByPuuid(std::string token, std::string entitlement, json puuidList, std::string region)
{
    std::vector<valorantUser> userList;
    std::string response;
    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_URL, std::string("https://pd." + region + ".a.pvp.net/name-service/v2/players").c_str());

    struct curl_slist* headers = NULL;

    std::string auth = "Authorization: Bearer " + token;
    std::string ent = "Entitlements: " + entitlement;
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, auth.c_str());
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, ent.c_str());
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");
    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);

    std::string toSend = puuidList.dump();
    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, toSend.c_str());


    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &response);
    CURLcode ret = curl_easy_perform(hnd);
    
    json resData = json::parse(response);
    for (int i = 0; i < resData.size(); i++)
    {
        valorantUser dat;
        dat.displayName = std::string(resData[i]["DisplayName"]);
        dat.puuid = std::string(resData[i]["Subject"]);
        dat.name = std::string(resData[i]["GameName"]);
        dat.tag = std::string(resData[i]["TagLine"]);
        userList.push_back(dat);
    }

    return userList;
}

std::string getTokenPuuid(std::string token)
{
    std::vector<std::string> toks;
    std::stringstream test(token);
    std::string cur;
    while (std::getline(test, cur, '.'))
    {
        toks.push_back(cur);
    }

    json decoded = json::parse(base64_decode(toks[1]));
    
    return decoded["sub"];
}

int main()
{
    
    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "");
    
    authCookies(); //get auth cookies
    std::string token = getAuthToken("username", "password"); //get auth token
    cookieReauth(); //get more auth cookies
    
    std::string entitlement = getEntitlement(token); //get entitlement token
    
    std::string puuid = getTokenPuuid(token); //get user puuid from token
    json puuidList = json::array({puuid});
    valorantUser botData = getUsersByPuuid(token, entitlement, puuidList, "na")[0]; //get user name from puuid

    std::cout << "Signed in as " << botData.name << "#" << botData.tag;
}
```

[image]
[image]

Thanks

Edit:
By commenting out all of my functions, the error stopped. If I remove the comment from even the authCookies() function, the error comes back. It is also very strange that the error does not appear until the end of the code.

```
int main()
{

    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "");
    
    /*
    authCookies(); //get auth cookies
    std::string token = getAuthToken("username", "password"); //get auth token
    cookieReauth(); //get more auth cookies

    std::string entitlement = getEntitlement(token); //get entitlement token

    std::string puuid = getTokenPuuid(token); //get user puuid from token
    json puuidList = json::array({ puuid });
    valorantUser botData = getUsersByPuuid(token, entitlement, puuidList, "na")[0]; //get user name from puuid

    std::cout << "Signed in as " << botData.name << "#" << botData.tag;*/
    curl_easy_cleanup(hnd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does the call stack say? Can you narrow it down to a specific piece of your code?

Comment: @RetiredNinja I edited the original post with some more info. I also found that by commenting out the curl_easy_perform line of my authCookies() function the error went away, but then the request is not being made.

Comment: If you set `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` but don't set `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA` the value passed is not a `std::string*` so I assume that just goes all sorts of wrong if it is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `authCookies()` is called, `WriteCallback` gets `userp` set to something that is `(void*)stdout` (default value if `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA` is not assigned). `((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);` dereferences `FILE*` as `std::string*`.

---

Why do you cast `char* contents` to `char*`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this fixed my problem! This is my first curl project (I've done this stuff in other languages). As far as the casting, that was in an example I saw online. I do not know why they cast it either.